# Debuging GWT with IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gwt, configuration

I am currently working on an old GWT project. Project docs were made to develop on eclipse but I prefer to use Intellij.

Running the project with GWT Development Mode is not a problem, but debugging it is something else.

I already read some openned questions about this subject but none of them seems to work with me.

Here is my configuration right now :
[image: Run/Debug Configuration]
I am using gwt 2.3.0 version which force me to use an old firefox 26 version to be able to use Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin. This version is also too old to use Super Dev Mode (who came with 2.5.1).

I am running IntelliJ 2019 3.1 (Ultimate Edition)

So my question is : what do I miss to successfully debug my 2.3.0 GWT application ?

Comment: what is the error message, that you've got?

Comment: I dont have any error message, I just can't debug. My app is working fine but there is no way for me to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeed debugging my app by adding a remote pointing to the same port as the one used by GWT.

Here is my remote config:

[image]

I have to run my app as usual and debug my remote to make everything works fine.